# how to share a variable inside actionListener (java)

Tags: java, awt, actionlistener

I'm trying to make a  preference menu and trying to share a variable that is inside action listener. Thanks in advance

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource()==buttonp1) {
        player_c=c1.getText();
        if(player_c.equalsIgnoreCase("blue")) {
            p1_color="blue";
    //i want to share a String with another class.
        }
        if(player_c.equalsIgnoreCase("red")) {
            p1_color="red";
        }
        if(player_c.equalsIgnoreCase("green")) {
            p1_color="green";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the variable to a different class, and pass an instance to the listener (probably by lexical scope).

```
class Player {
    private String color;
    // ...
    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = Objects.requireNonNull(color);
    }
}

// ...

   Player p1 = ...;
   // (Watch the repetition.)
   blue.addActionListener(event -> {
       p1.setColor("blue");
   });
   red.addActionListener(event -> {
       p1.setColor("red");
   });
   green.addActionListener(event -> {
       p1.setColor("green");
   });
   // ...
```

Comment: can you elaborate? sorry I'm still pretty new to GUI